# Is it possible to use File class (Java) in ajax Request (JavaScript)?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, file

I have a simple question.

I have a piece of code to upload a picture to my server. This code is developped in Javascript. It's a simple Javascript code which append File object (javascript) to my ajax request.

```
this.addPicture = function(file) {
var frm = new FormData();
frm.append("picture", file);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/myserverurl", true);
xhr.send(frm);
```

It it possible to use File Object (Java) in this request ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you asking about using a Java `File` object on the client side (in the browser) or on the server side (to handle the upload)?

Comment: My question is more in client side

Answer (score 1):

No. Java and Javascript are completely different languages, and you can't use Java APIs in a Web page's Javascript. You might want to look at the HTML `FileUpload` form control for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not possible also to create a File Object (Javascript Browser ) in Java and passed it to my API. In fact, my Java code called Javascript APi throw PhoneGap interface

Answer (score 0):

Basically you wouldn't be able to use java inplace of javascript if that's the question.

You could sent the request as mentioned in your code above and then either handle it as a file object on the server side code in java